# Creating sub-module in MongoDB while loading test data from json file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to load default data into my MongoDB database from a node.js backend.
This is the data I am loading as JSON:

```
[
    {
        "datetime": "28/08/2021 16:01:00",
        "sensor": {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "Temperature"
        },
        "value": 2502
    },
    {
        "datetime": "28/08/2021 16:02:00",
        "sensor": {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "Temperature"
        },
        "value": 2252
    }
]
```

And these are the `mongoose` models:

```
const SensorType = Object.freeze({
    Temperature: "Temperature"
});

const SensorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: Number, required: true },
    type: { type: Object.values(SensorType), required: true },
});

Object.assign(SensorSchema.statics, { SensorType });

const Sensor = mongoose.model('Sensor', SensorSchema);

const DataEntrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    datetime: { type: String, required: true },
    sensor: { type: SensorSchema, required: true },
    value: { type: Number, required: true }
});
  
const DataEntry = mongoose.model('DataEntry', DataEntrySchema);
```

Loading the DataEntries like this:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/",{
        useCreateIndex:true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true}
).then(() => {
    console.log('Database Successfully Connected')
    if(fill_default_data) {

      DataEntry.create(
        JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'test_data.json'), 'utf8'))
      );

    }
  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  }
);
```

However, I am noticing that no Sensor-objects are created inside MongoDB, only DataEntries - why is that? And how can I create Sensor-objects as well?

Of course, a DataEntry object has the sensor attached but if I call `Sensor.find().then( sensors => res.json(sensors) )` an empty array is returned.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `Object.assign(SensorSchema.statics, { SensorType });`? It appears to be an issue related to how you are using `statics` here combined with the `Object.assign()` in your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't use a schema in another schema. You need to use refs instead.

So something like this `sensor: { type: SensorSchema, required: true }` won't work.
You should replace it with `sensor: { type: number, required: true, ref: 'Sensor' },`, where the ref is the name of the model you want to refer to as a string. Notice that the type is a `number` as you want to pass the `id` of the relevant `SensorDocument` in the `DataEntryDocument`.

Moreover `id` is a virtual, you should use `_id` instead when you want to spec out ids in mongoose schemes.
So your mongoose schemes should look like:

```
const SensorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number, required: true },
    type: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required: true },
});

const Sensor = mongoose.model('Sensor', SensorSchema);

const DataEntrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    datetime: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required: true },
    sensor: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number, ref: 'Sensor', required: true },
    value: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number, required: true }
});
  
const DataEntry = mongoose.model('DataEntry', DataEntrySchema);
```

I still don't know why the Object.freeze and Object.assign are here.

Now if you want a DataEntry, you first need to create a Sensor.

```
const sensor = new Sensor({ _id: 0, type: 'Temperature' })
await sensor.save()

const dataEntry = new DataEntry({ sensor: 0, datetime: 'some timestamp as string', value: 25 })
await dataEntry.save()
```

I am leaving the validation-specific logic out as it is out of the scope of this query.

You can checkout [docs for mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for more information.